# How to store temp files in SharePoint 2010 hosted code?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a hosted web service in SharePoint 2010 that does uploads and downloads to sharepoint.
Because the files can be large (100MB+), i would much rather use temp files as the streams the code goes through instead of memory-streams to avoid 100mb memory allocations each time it does download/upload.

The problem is that i could find a location in the server to store temp files. System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() throws an error because the authenticated user doesn't have permissions to %TEMP% folder in the server.
"%systemroot%\temp" allows writing files but not deleting them.

Any idea if i can get a location from sharepoint that is accessible for any authenticated user to store the files?

few notes:

1. the files are temporary and need to be deleted right away so no need to consider clustering issues.
2. I don't want a solution that requires doing any active action in the servers as this plugin might be deployed on farms with a lot of servers and i'd hate to ask the customer to go through each server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access files under SharePoint's "system account". And yes, System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() is correct location.

Starting point - [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx).

Notes

- If you can open files as "temporary + delete on close" (check appropriate flags in FileStream class).
- Be extremely careful not to perform access to other SharePoint resource (SPFile/SPItem...) while running code inside RunWithElevatedPrivileges delegate.
- You may only need to open file under RunWithElevatedPrivileges, read/write may work outside - please verify yourself. I'd keep all file access inside delegates running with RunWithElevatedPrivileges.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best place but I have used the _layouts directory in the  hive before (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS) for doing something similar to this before.

You can get this location with Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath() and you should be able to read/write in the directory. You may need to run as elevated permissions.

Comment: Based on my experience with HttpHandlers in a custom SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010 web services, I have found that files under layouts are open to all authenticated users and even anonymous users if the IIS site is set to allow anonymous.  Basically, no SharePoint permissions are applied except within code inside ASPX pages that are under layouts.