# sharepoint event receiver security exception

Tags: c#, security, sharepoint, iis, gac

I have a SharePoint 2010 event receiver that listens for add/update/delete events on a SharePoint list.  When an event occurs the event receiver written in C# needs to pass these events to a Java program.  My code is posted below.  I can deploy the receiver fine and it works.  I get all the SharePoint events I need.  Now my problem is passing these events to Java.  I get security exceptions every time I try to open a socket or write out SharePoint events to a file.  For example, look at the ItemDeleting method I posted below that fires every time an item is deleted from a SharePoint list.  When I try to open a socket to Java I get System.Net.DnsPermission exception.  If I don't open a socket and try to write to a file instead, I get a System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission exception.

I looked around the forums and I tried a couple of things to troubleshoot it.  First, I set trust level="Full" in web.xml of SharePoint.  Then I set the DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" of my assembly.  This doesn't help.  What else can I do?  Thank you in advance for your responses.

My event receiver code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace EventReceiverTest
{

    public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
    {

       public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdding(properties);
       }

       public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemUpdating(properties);
       }

       public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           //can't open a socket connection.Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.DnsPermission,... failed
           TcpClient tc = new TcpClient("192.168.xxx.xxx", xxx);
           Console.WriteLine("Server invoked");
           NetworkStream ns = tc.GetStream();
           StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
           sw.WriteLine("item deleted");
           sw.Flush();
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
           Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());


           //can't write to file.  Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission,...failed
           System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\logs\\test.txt");
           file.WriteLine("item deleted " + properties.ListItem);

           //can't output anything to a console
           Console.Out.WriteLine("deleting an item ");

           base.ItemDeleting(properties);

           //but this part works
           properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
           properties.ErrorMessage = "Deleting items from " + properties.RelativeWebUrl + " is not supported.";
       }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Properties>
    <Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="true" />
  </Properties>
</Feature>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="EventReceiver3.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
  </Assemblies>
  <FeatureManifests>
    <FeatureManifest Location="EventReceiver3_Feature1\Feature.xml" />
  </FeatureManifests>
</Solution>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need FullTrust and run code that accesses system resources (like files) under "SharePoint:System" account.

Starting point - [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx).

See [How to store temp files in SharePoint 2010 hosted code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116218/how-to-store-temp-files-in-sharepoint-2010-hosted-code/11116685#11116685) .

Comment: Spasibo Alexei.  I changed the code to what you suggested and I no longer get exceptions.  However, I now get an error on the GUI whenever I try to add/delete files.  It says Error creating instance of sandboxed code object. The object cannot be created from sandboxed code assembly.  This only happens when my code is running.  Do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: Not sure. I think you have receiver that is sandboxed and as result can't do many things. You may need to deploy it differently (farm wide feature?) if it is the case. Check out logs for more useful info.